# Why is this program giving me a IndexError: list index out of range error but only sometimes

Tags: python, loops

My program is giving me the IndexError: list index out of range which I'm familiar with but the strange part that I don't know how to deal with is that it is only giving me the error maybe 1 in 5 times on average. The majority of the time it will run fine without errors but the odd time it will give me the IndexError message and not run. The error is coming from line 44 involving something with the for loop.

If there is no visible errors, I'd appreciate if you could run this code to let me know if it is just my computer or if it is an error in the code since the error only comes up on occasion and is not consistent.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import string

grid_size = 10

grid = [ [ '_' for _ in range(grid_size) ] for _ in range(grid_size) ]

orientations = [ 'leftright', 'updown', 'diagonalup', 'diagonaldown' ]

class Button(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs, font=("Courier", 14))

class LabelSmall(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs, font=("Courier", 14))

class Label(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs, font=("Courier", 44))

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        def mainFunc():
            handle = open('dictionary.txt')
            words = handle.readlines()
            handle.close()
            words = [ random.choice(words).upper().strip() \
            for _ in range(5) ]
            print ("The words are:")
            print(words)
            def listWords():
                word_length = len(word)
                LabelSmall(self, text="The words are:").grid(row=0, column=grid_size+1)
                for i in range(word_length):
                    LabelSmall(self, text=words[i]).grid(row=i+1, column=grid_size+1)
            Button(self, text="Reshuffle Grid", command=mainFunc).grid(row=grid_size, column=grid_size+1)
            for word in words:
                word_length = len(word)

                placed = False
                while not placed:
                    orientation = random.choice(orientations)

                    if orientation == 'leftright':
                        step_x = 1
                        step_y = 0
                    if orientation == 'updown':
                        step_x = 0
                        step_y = 1
                    if orientation == 'diagonalup':
                        step_x = 1
                        step_y = -1
                    if orientation == 'diagonaldown':
                        step_x = 1
                        step_y = 1

                    x_position = random.randrange(grid_size)
                    y_position = random.randrange(grid_size)

                    ending_x = x_position + word_length*step_x
                    ending_y = y_position + word_length*step_y

                    if ending_x < 0 or ending_x >= grid_size: continue
                    if ending_y < 0 or ending_y >= grid_size: continue

                    failed = False


                    for i in range(word_length):
                        character = word[i]

                        new_position_x = x_position + i*step_x
                        new_position_y = y_position + i*step_y

                        character_at_new_position = grid[new_position_x][new_position_y]
                        if character_at_new_position != '_':
                            if character_at_new_position == character:
                                continue
                            else:
                                failed = True
                                print("failed")


                    if failed:
                        print('randomizing spot')
                        for row in range(grid_size):
                            for column in range(grid_size):
                                if ( grid[row][column] == '_' ):
                                    txt = random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
                                    Label(self, text=txt).grid(row=row, column=column)
                        continue
                    else:
                        for i in range(word_length):
                            character = word[i]

                            new_position_x = x_position + i*step_x
                            new_position_y = y_position + i*step_y

                            grid[new_position_x][new_position_y] = character
                            for row in range(grid_size):
                                for column in range (grid_size):
                                    if ( grid[row][column] == grid[new_position_x][new_position_y] ):
                                        grid[row][column] = grid[new_position_x][new_position_y]
                                        Label(self, text=character).grid(row=row, column=column)
                        placed = True
            #restartButton = Button(self, text = "Reshuffle Grid", command = mainFunc)
            listWords()
        mainFunc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe if you gave *some* idea what this is supposed to be doing, you'd improve your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace which shows the offending line? Counting to 44 is tedious.

Comment: if some debugging is done, you will want to find something related to this error which means "you're trying to access an element which is not within the list or range of elements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line where you initialize a for loop (for word in words:), the line right after it, you set the variable `'wordlength = len(word)`. Let's say that the string 'word' has a length of 5.

In your code, I can see that you have a variable called 'failed'. During your iterations of (`for i in range(word_length):` [the one after you initialize failed = false]), you set `character = word[i]`. Since you have a length of 5, and lists start from 0, ultimately meaning that when you get to `word[5]`, you will get `IndexError`.

This same concept of error is seen in the else section of your if/else statement after the loop described above.

P.S. Please put line numbers when you post something large like this because this was pretty annoying.

Comment: Would the easiest fix if I'm understand right be to subtract 1? As in [i-1] so that it goes 0,1,2,3,4 instead of 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: Yes, that should work. If it doesn't work, there may be another error in the code which I couldn't identify.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try it out and give an update later.

Comment: Update: I'm now getting this error: _IndexError: list index out of range_ and it is occurring on line 45, which is this: `LabelSmall(self, text=words[i-1]).grid(row=i+1, column=grid_size+1)` (this line is the "for i in range(word_length)" line in the listWords function)